# the icon of fullscreen in the inappwebview is too small in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can make an icon of the full screen in inappwebview library bigger and the other icon of the video player in html?

Comment: Hello, to help you better, you should edit your question adding some sample code and the visual output you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

we should set the useWideViewPort:false in AndroidInAppWebViewOption

```dart
InAppWebView(
               initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                 android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                   useWideViewPort: false,
                 ),
                 ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                   enableViewportScale: false,
                 ),
                 crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                   debuggingEnabled: true,
                   javaScriptEnabled: true,
                 ),
               ),

               onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController webViewController) {
                 _controller.complete(webViewController);
                 _webViewController = webViewController;

                 if (data.item3) {
                   _webViewController.loadUrl(url:data.item2.link);
                 }
               },
               onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController webViewController,String url) {
                 _webViewController = webViewController;
                 print('Page started loading: $url');
               },
               onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController webViewController,String url) {
                 _webViewController = webViewController;
                 print('Page finished loading: $url');
               },

             ),
```